# A tank, shaped like a cone has a height of 15 meters and a base radius of 6 meters. The cone is standing up, with the circular part as its base.

Tags: calculus, integration

A tank, shaped like a cone has a height of $15$ meters and a base radius of $6$ meters. The
cone is standing up, with the circular part as its base. It is full of water, and we want to
pump all of it out through a pipe that is at the tip of the cone. Assume that the density
of water is $\rho = 1000~\text{kg}/\text{m}^3$ and the acceleration due to gravity is $g = 9.8~\text{m}/\text{s}^2$
.

Set up the integral of the work done to pump all the water out of the tank. DO NOT
EVALUATE THE INTEGRAL. [Note: You can use ρ and g in your answer; you do not
have to use 1000 and 9.8.]

**My attempt**

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 15 }{ (1000)(9.8)\left(\frac { 4\pi y^ 2 }{ 25 }\right)(15-y)dy }$$

but the answer was $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 15 }{ (1000)(9.8)\left[\frac { 2(15-y) }{ 5 }\right]^ 2(15-y)dy }$$

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried to get your answer? We can help you find which part you made a mistake.

Comment: It looks like there is a factor of $\pi$ missing from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the $A(y)$ seems to be the problem

The tank is a cone, so the radius of the cross section increases linearly with $h$

At $y=0$, $r=6$ and at $y=15$, $r=0$

So

$$r(y)=\frac{6}{15}(15-y)$$

$$A(y)=\pi \left[\frac{6(15-y)}{15}\right]^2=\pi \left[\frac{2(15-y)}{5}\right]^2$$

Comment: Can you please explain me briefly

Comment: Sure, the $6$ in the fraction $\frac{6}{15}$ comes from what the radius is at maximum (at the base when $y = 0$), and at $y=0$, in order to return $r$ to 6, we have to divide (modulate) by 15. 

$r(y)$ is now linearized in $y$ and satisfies what we want it to do, namely $r(0) = 6$ and $r(15)=0$